# Consider the experiment of choosing a point at random on a disk of radius $r$. Let $X$ be the squared distance between the point and r. Find $F(x)$

Tags: probability

Consider the experiment that consists of choosing a point at random from the interior
of a disk of radius $r$. Let $X$ be the square of the distance between the chosen point and the center
of the disk. Find The Distribution Function Of $X$.

$F(x)$ is the funcion of distribution.
Here is what I thought
$\Omega=\{x\in \Re : x\leq r \wedge x\geq0 \}$

$X=r^{2}$

$R_{x}=[0,r^{2}]$
In my opinion, this random variable is distributed uniform.

I thought $F(x)$ as $\int_\infty^x 1/r^{2} dx$. Is easy to prove that the integral over the range is equal to 1.  Am I right?

Comment: Between the point and $r$?

Comment: Yes, between the point and r

Comment: I thought $r$ was a real number. Now it seems that $r$ is some point of the disk?

Comment: No, r is the radio of the disk. The distance between a point and their radio is r at maximum (when the point is at border). And the minimum distance is 0, when the point is at the center. That´s the reason of the range.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write the $dx$ in the  distribution function to make things clear.

Comment: Sorry. I just edited the post. The original is in spanish so I could have translated badly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=(X_1,X_2)\sim \textrm{Uniform}(B(0,r))$ and $\|X\|^2_2=X_1^2+X_2^2$. We have
$$P(\|X\|_2^2\leq z)=P(\{(x,y)\in B(0,r):x^2+y^2\leq z\})=\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\int_{\{(x,y)\in B(0,r):x^2+y^2\leq z\}}d\lambda^2=\frac{(z\wedge r^2)}{r^2}$$